# Converting Image URL into to a renderable picture

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently using the NewsData.IO API to develop a website with trending news. The question I have is how am I supposed to convert image urls into actual pictures on my website. Using the api, im able to obtain the image url for each article, but im sort of confused on how to convert the link to an image. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
//For Cryptocurrency Prices (CoinRanking)
const key = 'XXXX';
const url = 'https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?' + key;

//For Tech News (NewsData.IO)
const key2 = 'XXXX'
const url2 = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=' + key2 +'&category=technology,business,science&language=en'

//Loads Crypto Data
async function loadPrices() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    const coins = (await response.json()).data.coins;

    const helloElm = document.getElementById("hello");


    // loop through all coins
    let output = '';
    for (var coin of coins) {
        output += "<div class=grid-container> <br />" + coin["price"] + "<br />" + ", " + coin["name"] + "</div>" ;
    }
    helloElm.innerHTML = output
}


//Loads Crypto Data
async function GetNews() {
  const response = await fetch(url2);
  
  const news = (await response.json()).results;

  const helloElm = document.getElementById("goodbye");

  document.getElementById("goodbye").innerHTML +="<div class ='grid-container'></div>"

  // loop through all news articles
  let output = '';
  for (var newNews of news) {
      output += "<center> <div class=grid-item <br />" + "<b> <u>"+ newNews["image_url"] + "<br />" + newNews["title"] + "</u> </b>" + "<br />" + "<br />" + newNews["description"] + "<br />" + "<br />"  + "Publisher: " + newNews["source_id"] + "<br />" + "<a href=" + newNews["link"] + ">Want to view the article?</a>"  + "</div> </center>";
  }
  helloElm.innerHTML = output

}
```

Comment: If you have the image URL, you need to place it on the page in an `<img>` tag, just like you would with any other image in HTML. Also, do not use the `<center>` tag as it is deprecated (and has been for years).

Comment: if you have the image url source you are you able to just place that in the source attribute of the img tag: <img src={newNews["image_url"]} />